# .net MVC3 Counterpart to PHP script tag

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

**I have the following script tag from a PHP page:**

```
 <script src='/get_items.php'></script>
```

**What would be its counterpart ideally in .Net MVC3 view (say I want to call an action method)?**

PS: The php script tag returns function calls (as observed thru Fiddler), ie:

RegisterThis('123', ["Title",{"1111":["Title Text","","</h2>","1","5","0",[]]}]);

RegisterThis('234', ["Title",{"2222":["Title Text","","</h2>","1","0","6",[]]}]);

RegisterThis('345', ["Title",{"3333":["Title Text","","</h2>","1","8","0",[]]}]);

**(I'm not asking about creating a JSon Script, just how to have a counterpart to the script tag in the view as it is in the php page.)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `Url.Action` helper. For example in a Razor view:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Action("GetItems", "Home")"></script>
```

and then of course you would have the `GetItems` action on `HomeController` that will be called and it must return valid javascript:

```
public ActionResult GetItems()
{
    return JavaScript("the script you want to return");
}
```

and since the script sample you have shown resembles JSONP (it's not exactly JSONP, because you are passing 2 arguments to the callback and you are calling the callback multiple times ), you could write a custom `JsonpResult`:

```
public class JsonpResult : JsonResult
{
    public JsonpResult(object data)
    {
        Data = data;
        JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.Write("RegisterThis(");
        base.ExecuteResult(context);
        response.Write(")");
    }
}
```

and then have your controller action return an instance of this custom `JsonpResult` class and passing it a view model to be serialized into JSON and passed as argument to the callback javascript function.

Comment: Darin Dimitrov - YOU ARE THE MAN !!!!! Not only was your answer correct on the view side, but your added snippet on returning JavaScript on the ActionMethod made my return (via Fiddler) EXACTLY as that of the PHP page I wanted to replicate. Thanks again !!

Answer (score 0):

To just add C#/VB code to the page, you can use the <% %> tags in your .aspx. If it's a single function call that returns a value, you can use <%: %> which will even HTML encode the result. Check out this page with more information: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/asp-net-mvc-views-overview-cs.

To specifically load an action, use the HTML Helper method @Html.Action. Check out this page for more info: http://buildstarted.com/2010/09/29/htmlhelper-guide-for-mvc-3-part-2/.